# Creating an automated line to delinate borders on an image in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently using test photos of cattle loaded into R in hopes that I can find some way to automatically determine the slope of the back of the animal based on an image. Using some clever codes found online of ggplot2 I have been able to recreate the image in R in many shades and colors even in a graphical representation. However, I was wondering if there may be a possibility of determining the slope of the animals back potentially by asking the program to delineate the colors and find that border where the back and the background meet, then graph that as a line and display the slope of that line.

Thank You for your help.

Here is my current code used so far:

```
install.packages("jpeg")
library(jpeg)
url <- "http://www.centerforfoodsafety.org/files/dairy-cow_07982.jpg"

# Download the file and save it as "Image.jpg" in the directory
d_healthy_cow <- download.file(url,'url.jpg', mode = 'wb')
img_healthy_cow <- readJPEG("url.jpg") # Read the image

library("grid")
library("gridExtra")

#Place image on graph scale

# Obtain the dimension
imgDm <- dim(img_healthy_cow)
imgDm

#Assign RGB channels to data frame
imgRGB <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:imgDm[2], each = imgDm[1]),
  y = rep(imgDm[1]:1, imgDm[2]),
  R = as.vector(img_healthy_cow[,,1]),
  G = as.vector(img_healthy_cow[,,2]),
  B = as.vector(img_healthy_cow[,,3])
)

library(ggplot2)

# ggplot theme to be used
plotTheme <- function() {
   theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(
      size = 3,
      colour = "black",
      fill = "white"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(
      size = 2),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(
      colour = "gray80",
      linetype = "dotted"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(
      colour = "gray90",
      linetype = "dashed"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(
      size = rel(1.2),
      face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(
      size = rel(1.2),
      face = "bold"),
    plot.title = element_text(
      size = 20,
      face = "bold",
      vjust = 1.5)
  )
}
#Plot the image
ggplot(data = imgRGB, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(colour = rgb(imgRGB[c("R", "G", "B")])) +
  labs(title = "Original Image: Healthy Cow") +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y") +
plotTheme()

#K means Clustering
kClusters <- 3
kMeans <- kmeans(imgRGB[, c("R", "G", "B")], centers = kClusters)
kColours <- rgb(kMeans$centers[kMeans$cluster,])

ggplot(data = imgRGB, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(colour = kColours) +
  labs(title = paste("k-Means Clustering of", kClusters, "Colours")) +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y") + 
plotTheme()
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use `geom_raster` instead of `geom_point` – but your image is so big (480,000+ rows) that you will still face long plotting time.